# How to implementation 360video using Unity3D in virtual relaity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, 360-virtual-reality

I want to make a 360video app using unity.To make 360video app when i connect the 360video in unity and run ,but i don't get proper 360vide.I get the video runs so slow and the video don't sow in 360 video format, it show in 2D video. Now how can i solve the problem?

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, next time you post on Stack Overflow, try to show what you do, and what did you try, or people will not respond to you.

1.Put some **new GameObject** on your scene, a 3D Object (if you want to display a 360 video, I will recommend you to use a simple **Sphere**).

2.Attach **AudioSource** component to the sphere.

3.Attach **VideoPlayer** component to the Sphere, specify your video source, if it's URL or a directly video clip. Add your AudioSource to the VideoPlayer (at the bottom you will see the place to attach it).

4.Attach a new **shader** to the **sphere material** to flip sphere-normals, so the video will be displayed INTO the sphere, not ONTO the sphere.

The shader should be something like:

```
Shader "Flipping Normals" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {

        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        Cull Off

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert
        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
            v.normal.xyz = v.normal * -1;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
             fixed3 result = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
             o.Albedo = result.rgb;
             o.Alpha = 1;
        }

        ENDCG

    }

      Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```